# get element by Id Using Razor syntax

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

is it possible to get an HTML element by it's Id in a Razor Code block? for example some where in a view this element exists.

`<Input id='NameField' type='text'>`

and further down in the view there is a razor code block

```
@{
.... do some stuff
.... etc.
.... etc.
.... etc.

var nameTxtElement = GetElementById("NameField');

}
```

I know how to do this using Jquery, but I was just wondering if it is possible to do using Razor?

the primary reason being converting webforms with code behind to MVC, without implementing fully blown asp.net support into my MVC application.

Comment: Razor just generates text.  That wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: razor doesn't just generate text, you can create Variables, functions etc. inside a razor block, you can even dynamically build jquery (generating text, yes) but the Razor engine can do much more, or I hope it can...

Comment: All those can do is help you generate text.  My point is that Razor doesn't have anything remotely resembling a DOM.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do once you have your `var nameTxtElement`? You could probably accomplish the scenario with Razor, but you might have to think a little differently than if you were using WebForms. For example, you could do something like this...

```
@{ 
 //...
 var cssClass = "something"; 
 // ...
}

<input id='namefield' type='text' class='@cssClass' />
```

... if you wanted to insert a CSS class dynamically.

Comment: basically doing manipulation of the input, making it readonly or setting it's value, or dynamically adding validation. the key is not having to re-write a bunch of existing code behind logic, but I'm thinking that your example may be the only way to accomplish the task, again it just means re-writing a bunch of code that has been tested and works, I would prefer not to do. thanks for your reply Ben H.